# Why can I not upgrade to Lion?

Tags: installation, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, mac-app-store

I am trying to upgrade my MacBook Air's OS from Snow Leopard to Lion.

When I attempt to redeem my Download Code for Lion, the App Store notes that "Additional security information is needed." Afterwards, it leads me to this page that never loads:

> https://myinfo.apple.com/?&language-iso=US-EN&prs_account_nm=davidfaux%40gmail.com

… because "Safari can't make a secure connection."

What is going on?

Comment: I suggest not using a URL shortener (`goo.gl`). It will help people understand your problem if you give the real, original URL so that it is easily readable.

Comment: Sorry, good point.

Comment: Even `https//myinfo.apple.com` doesn't load. Try without HTTPS, just HTTP. It will redirect you.

Comment: Hope you don't have a problem with your email id out in the public as part of the URL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just wants you to log in to your Apple/iTunes account, possibly to verify your email address or have you accept some terms.

Now the actual problem here seems to be that it sends you to a non-working URL (the server does't seem to be configured to speak SSL on it's HTTPS port). As was already suggested, you can change the URL from `https://..` to `http://..` and should get redirected, or simply visit https://appleid.apple.com (click **Manage your account**) and log in there (with your Gmail address).